# Problems with scope declaring json objects

Tags: javascript, json

I am having an issue that I can't find the real root cause of it, I am guessing its a variable scope problem, but Im not really sure.

So, this is my code:

```
    beerslist = { thebeers : []};
    beerworld = { countries : []};
$.post("sample.php", function(data){
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                //alert(data.items);
                $.each(data.items, function(i, one){
                    beerslist.thebeers.push({
                        id : one.beer.bid,
                        name: one.beer.beer_name,
                        style : one.beer.beer_style,
                        abv : one.beer.beer_abv,
                        ibu : one.beer.beer_ibu,
                        rating : one.beer.rating_score,
                        my_rating : one.beer.auth_rating,
                        brewery : one.brewery.brewery_name,
                        country : one.brewery.country_name,
                        state : one.brewery.location.brewery_state,
                    });
                    //$("#beerlist").append("<div>" + one.beer.bid + "" + one.beer.beer_name + " " + one.beer.rating_score + " " + one.beer.auth_rating + " " + one.brewery.brewery_name + " " + one.beer.beer_style + " " + one.beer.beer_abv + " " + one.beer.beer_ibu + " " + one.brewery.country_name + "</div>");
                });
            });
    alert(JSON.stringify(beerslist));
        $.each(beerslist.thebeers, function(i,beer){
            var flag = false;

            $.each(beerworld.countries, function(j,country){
                if (country.name == beer.country){
                    flag = j;
                }                   
            });
            if (flag == false){
                beerworld.countries.push({
                    code : "AA",
                    name : beer.country,
                    state : beer.state,
                    rating : beer.my_rating,
                    ammount : 1,
                });
            } else {
                beerworld.countries[flag].ammount = beerworld.countries[flag].ammount + 1;
                beerworld.countries[flag].rating = (beerworld.countries[flag].rating + beer.my_rating)/2;   
            }
        });
        alert(JSON.stringify(beerworld));
        alert(JSON.stringify(beerslist));
```

When I trigger the first alert, It show an empty object with only the declaration value **"{"thebeers":[]}"**. So I go to the next step, where I iterate to create second json object and the array works normally, generating the "beerworld" apparentely without problems. I inserter alerts in this secon $.each node and all the calculations are right in there. But when I come out of the loop, the resulting object is all messed up, without the values I saw with the alerts using "**beerworld.countries[flag].rating**", for example, to validate.
Oh, and after this last $.each I can also access the object beerlist with no problems.

I appreciate any help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`Jquery Ajax` is asynchronous that's why your next code is executing before completing ajax request. This can be solved by callback. See following code:

```
beerslist = {
    thebeers: []
};
beerworld = {
    countries: []
};
$.post("sample.php", function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    //alert(data.items);
    $.each(data.items, function(i, one) {
        beerslist.thebeers.push({
            id: one.beer.bid,
            name: one.beer.beer_name,
            style: one.beer.beer_style,
            abv: one.beer.beer_abv,
            ibu: one.beer.beer_ibu,
            rating: one.beer.rating_score,
            my_rating: one.beer.auth_rating,
            brewery: one.brewery.brewery_name,
            country: one.brewery.country_name,
            state: one.brewery.location.brewery_state,
        });
        //$("#beerlist").append("<div>" + one.beer.bid + "" + one.beer.beer_name + " " + one.beer.rating_score + " " + one.beer.auth_rating + " " + one.brewery.brewery_name + " " + one.beer.beer_style + " " + one.beer.beer_abv + " " + one.beer.beer_ibu + " " + one.brewery.country_name + "</div>");
    });
    processResponseCallback(); //calling callback when your request is finish
});

function processResponseCallback() {
    alert(JSON.stringify(beerslist));
    $.each(beerslist.thebeers, function(i, beer) {
        var flag = false;

        $.each(beerworld.countries, function(j, country) {
            if (country.name == beer.country) {
                flag = j;
            }
        });
        if (flag == false) {
            beerworld.countries.push({
                code: "AA",
                name: beer.country,
                state: beer.state,
                rating: beer.my_rating,
                ammount: 1,
            });
        } else {
            beerworld.countries[flag].ammount = beerworld.countries[flag].ammount + 1;
            beerworld.countries[flag].rating = (beerworld.countries[flag].rating + beer.my_rating) / 2;
        }
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(beerworld));
    alert(JSON.stringify(beerslist));
}
```

Comment: So, @manwal, I'm still working on this. Now I need to work with pagination and I'm having the same kind of issue, I think.I'm using "while" on my code and my local json isn't being built on time. The start looks like this: **while (count < <?php echo $beercount; ?>){ $.post("getbeers.php", {offset: count}, function(data){** Even with the callback my "country" json is not being built right :(

Comment: Can you attach your code at bottom of question, how you are trying with pagination. I am not understanding.